# How to spot failure in a SQL Trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have this trigger set up on a table that is being updated by a 3rd party.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[onAddingPod] 
ON [dbo].[PODS] 
AFTER INSERT 
AS 
BEGIN
   UPDATE Jobs
   SET Job_POD_Supplied = 1
   FROM Jobs 
   INNER JOIN inserted ON Jobs.Job_ID = inserted.jobID
   WHERE (NOT (inserted.podID IS NULL))
END
```

It looks straight forward enough, but is failing to Update the Jobs record intermittently. The PODS record is still being added successfully.
I want to be able to track these failures, and would like to record the inserted.jobID and inserted.podID where the trigger has not worked.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: see if this helps http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165046(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: why don't you use merge/output and transaction,try-catch,return @error number.

Comment: Do you receive an error message when the update fails intermittently? Are you only missing the updates where podId is null?

Comment: What does "is failing" mean? Do you get an error message? If so, what is it?

Comment: I am not getting any error messages. Failure is where Job_POD_Supplied is not updated even though a new record has been inserted into PODS.

Comment: I am not getting any error messages. Failure is where Job_POD_Supplied is not updated even though a new record has been inserted into PODS. I do not know what procedure(s) the 3rd party might be using to add records to the PODS file.